# indexedDB: Delete function is not working

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

in the following set of function which is actually for `indexedDb`, in this `deleteTodo` in not working. i wrote down the following code from a site  and in there running example it is perfectly working. but in my code which i wrote down, in that `delete` function is not deleting that items. I analysed that code found that, as much i know, there is no mistake but since i am new to this technology(`indexedDB`) so i don't know where is the mistake?

here is my code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var html5rocks = {};
html5rocks.indexedDB = {};
html5rocks.indexedDB.db = null;

html5rocks.indexedDB.open = function() {
  var version = 1;
  var request = indexedDB.open("todos", version);

  request.onsuccess = function(e) {
    html5rocks.indexedDB.db = e.target.result;
    // Do some more stuff in a minute
  };

  request.onerror = html5rocks.indexedDB.onerror;
};
html5rocks.indexedDB.open = function() {
  var version = 1;
  var request = indexedDB.open("todos", version);

  // We can only create Object stores in a versionchange transaction.
  request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
    var db = e.target.result;

    // A versionchange transaction is started automatically.
    e.target.transaction.onerror = html5rocks.indexedDB.onerror;

    if(db.objectStoreNames.contains("todo")) {
      db.deleteObjectStore("todo");
    }

    var store = db.createObjectStore("todo",
      {keyPath: "timeStamp"});
  };

  request.onsuccess = function(e) {
    html5rocks.indexedDB.db = e.target.result;
    html5rocks.indexedDB.getAllTodoItems();
  };

  request.onerror = html5rocks.indexedDB.onerror;
};
html5rocks.indexedDB.addTodo = function(todoText) {
  var db = html5rocks.indexedDB.db;
  var trans = db.transaction(["todo"], "readwrite");
  var store = trans.objectStore("todo");
  var request = store.put({
    "text": todoText,
    "timeStamp" : new Date().getTime()
  });

  trans.oncomplete = function(e) {
    // Re-render all the todo's
    html5rocks.indexedDB.getAllTodoItems();
  };

  request.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log(e.value);
  };
};
html5rocks.indexedDB.getAllTodoItems = function() {
  var todos = document.getElementById("todoItems");
  todos.innerHTML = "";

  var db = html5rocks.indexedDB.db;
  var trans = db.transaction(["todo"], "readwrite");
  var store = trans.objectStore("todo");

  // Get everything in the store;
  var keyRange = IDBKeyRange.lowerBound(0);
  var cursorRequest = store.openCursor(keyRange);

  cursorRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
    var result = e.target.result;
    if(!!result == false)
      return;

    renderTodo(result.value);
    result.continue();
  };

  cursorRequest.onerror = html5rocks.indexedDB.onerror;
};// end of getAllTodoItems
function renderTodo(row) {
  var todos = document.getElementById("todoItems");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href="#";
  var t = document.createTextNode(row.text);
  //t.data = row.text;

  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    html5rocks.indexedDB.deleteTodo(row.text);
  });

  a.textContent = " [Delete]";
  li.appendChild(t);
  li.appendChild(a);
  todos.appendChild(li);
};
html5rocks.indexedDB.deleteTodo = function(id) {
  var db = html5rocks.indexedDB.db;
  var trans = db.transaction(["todo"], "readwrite");
  var store = trans.objectStore("todo");

  var request = store.delete(id);

  trans.oncomplete = function(e) {
    html5rocks.indexedDB.getAllTodoItems();  // Refresh the screen
  };

  request.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  };
};
function init() {
  html5rocks.indexedDB.open(); // open displays the data previously saved
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
function addTodo() {
  var todo = document.getElementById('todo');

  html5rocks.indexedDB.addTodo(todo.value);
  todo.value = '';
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is an experimental page...</h1>
<ul id="todoItems"></ul>
<input placeholder="add todo things" id='todo' type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="Add Todo Item" onclick="addTodo(); return false;">
</body>
```

and this is the link from where i wrote down this code: [html5rock](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/#)

please tell me where i am wrong.
anyFelp would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass to `delete` the key of the record, and you defined `timeStamp` to be the key, not `text`.

Replace

```
html5rocks.indexedDB.deleteTodo(row.text);
```

with

```
html5rocks.indexedDB.deleteTodo(row.timeStamp);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/koxogasonu/1/edit)

Comment: this is not working and futrher it is giving an error:  `Uncaught DataError: Failed to execute 'delete' on 'IDBObjectStore': No key or key range specified.`

Comment: @Annisaini Did you look at the demo ?

Comment: Maybe you copied the first version before edit when I wrote "timestamp" instead of "timeStamp" (the usual camelcase is "timestamp").

Comment: no i didn't relode my page so i could not get that. however, so much thankyou....